# Mysqli/PHP/HTML duplicate insert records when using mysqli_insert_id to pull recently autogenerated ID's

Tags: php, html, mysql

I currently Have this code for inserting into my receipt table,

```
$query = "insert into receipt(petname,receipttype)
                           values('$petname','$receipttype')";
```

in which i obtain the autogenerated id 
`$receiptid=mysqli_insert_id($db);`
and send it to the next page. however when the record is inserted, another is also generated (Two of the same content but another auto-generated ID, is entered into the database) 
http://prntscr.com/kpjff6 [example of duplicate fields with unique ids]

```
if (isset($_POST['cmdedit'])){

    $petname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['petname']);
    $receipttype =  mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['receipttype']);

    $query = "insert into receipt(petname,receipttype)
                       values('$petname','$receipttype')";



        $result = mysqli_query($db,$query);
            if (mysqli_query($db,$query)){
            $receiptid=mysqli_insert_id($db);           
            if ($result) {
                            echo "<font color = 'green' > Receipt sucessfully obtained! Page will auto-redirect to order confirmation page in 5 seconds! </font>";
                     header( "refresh:5; url=addorderhomepage.php?animalid=".$animalid."&receiptid=".$receiptid);

            }else{
                echo "<p>Something went wrong! </p>" . mysqli_error($db);
    }
    }
    }


  ?>
       <div class = "topbar">
      <h2> Order Receipt </h2>
     </div>

  <?php
  $query = "select *
                    from catalogue
                    where animalid= " . $animalid;

            $result = mysqli_query($db,$query);
    if ($result){
            while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                    ?>

      <form method = "post" action = "" >
        <table>
            <tr>
            <th> Animal ID</th>
            <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"> <input type ="text" name = "txtanimalid" value = "<?php echo $rows[0]; ?>" readonly /> </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <th> Animal Name </th>
            <td> <input type ="text" name = "petname" value = "<?php echo $rows[1]; ?>" readonly />  </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <th> Animal Type </th>
            <td> <input type ="text" name = "petname" value = "<?php echo $rows[3]; ?>" readonly />  </td>
            </tr>

              <tr>
            <th> Animal Species </th>
            <td> <input type ="text" name = "petname" value = "<?php echo $rows[2]; ?>" readonly />  </td>
            </tr>


             <tr>
            <th> Animal Description </th>
            <td> <input type ="text" name = "petname" value = "<?php echo $rows[4]; ?>" readonly />  </td>
            </tr>


             <tr>
            <th> Receipt type </th>
            <td> <input type ="text" name = "receipttype" value = "printable" readonly />  </td>
            </tr>   

            <tr>
            <th> Receipt Date  </th>
            <td> <input type ="date" name = "orderdate" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-j'); ?>" readonly="readonly"  </td>
            </tr>



            <tr>
            <th> <br/><br/> </th>
            <td> </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <th> </th>
            <td> <input type ="submit" value = "Obtain receipt" name = "cmdedit" /> </td>
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The duplicate row are probably happen because you are calling 2 time the mysqli_query with the same data, the first time when storing the response in the $result var and the second time inside the condition in the if statement.

```
   // ... code
   $result = mysqli_query($db,$query);
- if (mysqli_query($db,$query)) {
+ if ($result) {
      $receiptid = mysqli_insert_id($db);           
      if ($result) {
   // .. rest of the code
```

Comment: Great thank you, i'm honestly surprised how i made that mistake.